# How do I display a field from a referenced user?

Tags: 8

I have a content type A with a reference to a user and I would like to show a specific field from that user in nodes of that content type.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You might achieve this with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), by creating a view for nodes of that content type, and then adding a "relationship" to the user. The user fields will then become available for you to display.

You can find an introductory tutorial to start using Relationships with Views in "[How relationships work in Views and how to add a referencing entity relationship](http://buildamodule.com/video/advanced-site-building-in-drupal-7-advanced-views-how-relationships-work-in-views-and-how-to-add-a-referencing-entity-relationship)".

Comment: Thanks. I did that, and placed the block of the user-field view to be shown in the content type. But Its showing every users field. Do I have to add some filters?

Comment: @Finn you need to create a views relationship. There's a link in the answer about relationships, you should give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

Make a display mode for user which only contains one field:

admin/structure/display-modes/view/add/user

Then format the entity reference field in your node with that view mode, and you only have that specific field in your node display.